# .net Plugin system, how the plugin raises events and methods in the host app

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets, plugins

I'm building a TCP chat that supports plugins, so the user can download them and use them

I'm using this code to load the plugin and have have control of it's public variables and methods:
(this is vb.net but i accept c#)

`Dim obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Assembly.LoadFile("C:\...plugin folder...\Plugin.dll").GetType("Plugin.Main"))
obj.Initialize()`

But i can't raise an event or a method from the plugin to the host app
I want the plugin to have control on the server socket, so it can send data through it without the need of creating a new socket with different port, in the Host app i have a SendData public function that i want to access from the plugin

I've tried creating an event in the plugin and AddHandler to that on the host app, didn't work...

Any ideas?

Comment: Each question requires an elaborate answer to be able to explain clearly what you need to do. I strongly suggest that you divide your question into multiple stackoverflow questions so that you can get a great answer for each one.